# How to draw customer animations use Konva tweens?

Tags: konva

like this [bounce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8TJ7.gif) and this [lightspeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsEWd.gif)

im already use move ,rotate,fade,scale,etc, code like this

```
const { x, y } = moveXY;
const tween = creatTween({
  node: kvNode,
  x: x,
  y: y,
  duration: config.enter_duration / 1000, 
  easing: Konva.Easings[config.enter_easings], 
  yoyo: false, 
  onUpdate: function () {},
  onFinish: function () {
    if (!config.enter_direction) {
      tween.reset();
    }
  },
});
tween.play();
```

How can I achieve animation like above picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve it like that. Adjust the steps & values to receive the desired result:

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

const promisedTo = (shape, opts) => {
  return new Promise((res) => shape.to({ onFinish: res, ...opts }));
};

const sequentialAnimations = async (shape, defaultConfig, configs) => {
  for (let config of configs) {
    await promisedTo(shape, {
      ...defaultConfig,
      ...config,
      onUpdate: () => stage.batchDraw(),
    });
  }
};

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height,
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();

var rect = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  offsetX: 25,
  offsetY: 25,
  fill: 'green',
});

var rect2 = new Konva.Rect({
  x: 100,
  y: 200,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  offsetX: 25,
  offsetY: 25,
  fill: 'blue',
});

const bounce = (shape) => {
  const initialState = {
    scaleX: shape.scaleX(),
    scaleY: shape.scaleY(),
    opacity: shape.opacity(),
  };
  sequentialAnimations(shape, { easing: Konva.Easings.EaseInOut }, [
    { scaleX: 0.7, scaleY: 0.7, duration: 0.2 },
    { scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, duration: 0.2 },
    { opacity: 0, scaleX: 0.2, scaleY: 0.2, duration: 0.4 },
    { ...initialState, duration: 0.3 },
  ]);
};

const lightspeed = (shape) => {
  const initialState = {
    x: shape.x(),
    skewX: shape.skewX(),
    opacity: shape.opacity(),
  };
  sequentialAnimations(shape, { easing: Konva.Easings.EaseInOut }, [
    { skewX: -1, x: initialState.x - 100, opacity: 0, duration: 0.2 },
    { skewX: -2, x: -50, opacity: 0, duration: 0.4 },
    { ...initialState, duration: 0.3 },
  ]);
};

layer.add(rect, rect2);

stage.add(layer);
stage.batchDraw();

lightspeed(rect);
bounce(rect2);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" />
```